# .htaccess get value after last slash

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /category/.*/([^/]+)/?     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !category\.php      [NC]
RewriteRule  .*/category.php?cat=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I want to get last word from URL as `$_GET['cat']`, and it works, but when I put in URL only one or two slash then it doesn't work.

```
https://example.com/category - don't work
https://example.com/category/motorization - don't work
https://example.com/category/motorization/cars - work
https://example.com/category/motorization/cars/audi -work
```

Comment: Of course only the last one works, because your condition _demands_ four slashes ... How could you even expect that `https://example.com/category` would work, when you are demanding the whole thing to start with `/category/` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to capture anything after `/category/` in `$1`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?category(?:/(?:.*/)?([^/]+))?/?$ category.php?cat=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```